# Which statistical test should I use on 2 groups of performance time data

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences

I have 2 testsets consisting of values which are a set of time differences calculated by taking the difference of the moment of sending and the moment of arriving of a web request.

In one testset I use the traditional HTTP stack with TCP as transport protocol. The other, with completely the same setup uses a new transport protocol called QUIC. To use this protocol I include a library which takes care of the transport, the rest of the code remains exactly the same.

I want to analyse whether the results of these 2 testsets are statistically significantly different or not.

I have a hard time determining if this could be done with a paired T-test, unpaired T-test or two sample t-test as some people suggested. My bet initially was a paired T-test, but I'm not sure anymore as perhaps this situation is not the same as "the same patient being checked before and after getting a medicine". Which one do you recommended and why?

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is the difference between an unpaired t-test and a two-sample t-test? 2) What kind of pairing would you want to do? (It's a safe bet that if you struggle to answer this second one, it means that the paired t-test is inappropriate.)

Comment: 1. You haven't stated a specific null and alternative ("different" is vague! different *how*? Do you specifically need to address the mean or is something more general your intent?).  2. The distribution of times are likely to be (a) quite skew and (b) be such that the spread is likely to increase with the mean. A t-test is probably a poor choice, power-wise (and unless your sample sizes are very large, probably not so great on the significance level side). You should think carefully about both what you know about the behavior of such times, and what you need to find out about them.

Comment: @Dave: Ad 1) Apparently, there is no difference. Ad 2) Indeed, pairing is not possible. You can't use a web request as a "unit" to test twice with switching protocols. It will always be a new request susceptible to the side effects of the internet.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: "different" is: the mean of the second testset using QUIC will be lower than the first testset. Ad 1. the specific null would be no difference in the means of the two sets. Ad 2. When I put some results in a GraphPad quickcalcs tool as unpaired t test, indeed the more results, the more the standard deviation increases.